# Room-based code is causing the following error: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.mathreps.MathRepsApplication

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am working on adding data persistence to an app using the Room library, based on [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-update-data-room?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-5-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-update-data-room#3). My database only has one column where a String corresponding to a user-selected radio button is to be placed. However, as soon as I attempt to insert a new object (in this case, an `Attempt`), it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.mathreps.MathRepsApplication.
```

I believe this error comes from the following block of code within my Rating fragment:

```
private val dataViewModel: MathRepsViewModel by activityViewModels {
    MathRepsViewModel.MathRepsViewModelFactory(
        (activity?.application as MathRepsApplication).database
            .attemptDao()
    )
}
```

Which relates to a different class called MathRepsApplication

```
class MathRepsApplication: Application() {
    val database: AttemptRoomDatabase by lazy {AttemptRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this)}
}
```

Since this problem most likely relates to multiple classes and packages, [here](https://github.com/coocraig/mathreps) is the link to the repository for the project.

My attempts to fix this have been unsuccessful, with them mostly consisting of heavily reviewing the database implementation and not much else, as I don't exactly know where to start.

Comment: Did you forget to add your cushion Application subclass to the manifest?

Comment: Nope. That was exactly what was needed, thank you so much! Hard to think so much fret can be caused from one line!